# What's the better way of writing `*zoom: 1;`

Tags: css

I am trying to build my code. I copied some css files from legacy code, But when I tried to run

`yarn build`
I am able to see bunch of errors like

```
▲ [WARNING] Expected identifier but found "*" [css-syntax-error]

    <stdin>:122:2:
      122 │   *display: inline;
          ╵   ^


▲ [WARNING] Expected identifier but found "*" [css-syntax-error]

    <stdin>:123:2:
      123 │   *zoom: 1; }
          ╵   ^


▲ [WARNING] Expected identifier but found "*" [css-syntax-error]

    <stdin>:133:2:
      133 │   *display: inline;
```

I want to how exactly needed to replaced for fixed. From the question, I can understand something is wrong with `*`

I don't want to see any warning during yarn build.

Comment: You shouldn't be needing to support those anymore: those are for the bygone eras that even predates IE11 (and IE11 is already dead at this point). Those rules should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

`*` is deprecated. You don't need it anymore.

```
zoom: 1;
```

or

```
zoom: 100%;
```

[CSS zoom syntax documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom)

Comment: What about display ?

Comment: remove `*` from all the selectors. including display